# How to put Media Wiki source into org-mode document?

Tags: org-mode

My current workflow for most things in life is to create a TODO item in org-mode, build the solution up in the org-mode entry before pasting it elsewhere.

This has worked fine for me for quite a few years.  However I am currently creating [MediaWiki entries](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting) for a third party system using this approach.

However MediaWiki uses asterisks as bullet points so I have something like the following in my org-mode entry:

* bullet item 1

* bullet item 2

Obviously org-mode attempts to interpret these as headings and refuses to accept they are sub-entry of my

* MediaWiki entries

top level-heading.  I've tried surrounding the whole entry with #+BEGIN_EXAMPLE/#+END_EXAMPLE and #+BEGIN_SRC/#+END_SRC.  While this may impact any export it clearly doesn't force org-mode to consider my bullet lists any differently.

Is there anyway to tell org-mode to not process a particular section as org-mode source?

Thanks! Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a source block, you can escape asterisks by prefixing them with a comma.

If you have a mediawiki mode installed, and use `#begin_src mediawiki`, then you can freely edit your blocks in another buffer with C-c ', and the commas will be inserted for you when you finish editing.`

[Related answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39831094/605276).

Comment: Thanks for this - works like a charm :happy face: Don't know why I failed to turn up the related answer having searched for variations of  'org mode escape header char in verbatim text'